# Ajax Load swf File by Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is There a way to load swf file via jQuery Ajax Or after the page load complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to load the swf and call it whenever you like.

---

A full fledged example on loading the swf on an [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback will be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.5.1");
    google.load("swfobject", "2.2");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: "some url",
        context: document.body,
        success: function (msg) {
            LoadSWF();
        }
    });
    function LoadSWF(someData) {
        var flashvars = {
            name1: "hello",
            name2: "world",
            name3: "foobar"
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false"
        };
        var attributes = {
            id: "myDynamicContent",
            name: "myDynamicContent"
        };

        swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Elad Lachmi : you mean somthing like this : $(document).ready(function { swfobject.registerObject (...)} ) . is it $(windows).load better?

Comment: is it possible to detect the swf's load?