# How to show one of five videos at same location after specific link selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have five 5 divs, on hover of those div i am displaying content in a dialogue box right to it... right to dialogue box i want to put video of respective divs..

on hover of div1 it should show 1st video, on hover of 2nd div it should show 2nd video and so on...

So how to display different videos at same place on hover of respective divs???

Following is screenshot:
[image]

Please reply as early as possible..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one video object you can change the src property.
Haven't tested this yet, but it looks promising ...

**Approach 1:** store your video url's in an array

```
var initVideos = function(){
    var videos = ["http://urlVideo1.flv", "http://urlVideo2.flv", ...],
        videoArea = $("#videoArea"),
        divs = $("ul li div"); // or some other selector for your HTML

    // bind your hover event to the divs
    divs.hover(
        // mouseover
        function(){
            videoArea.show();
            videoArea.find("object > embed").prop("src", videos[$(this).index()]);
        },
        // mouseout
        function(){
            videoArea.hide();
        }
    );
};

// once the DOM is ready
(function(){
    initVideos();
});
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/J6WQm/

To finetune this you should change src only after loading the previous event was completed.
Otherwise when you hover too fast the browser might generate too much re-flow.

Also depending on the object you use code can vary. For the moment I'm only triggering the embed object (mozzila browsers) but the object (IE) should also be triggered on param movie value.

To counter these different objects program logic people used [swf object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456066/ajax-load-swf-file-by-jquery) to generate that code block for you. Now this has been outdated quite some time.

Therefor a more suitable approach may be to use [flashembed](http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/flashembed/index.html)

**Approach 2:** use the href property from the links in the menu

```
var initVideos = function () {
    var divs = $("ul li a");

    // bind your hover event to the divs
    divs.mouseenter(
        // mouseover
        function () {
            flashembed("videoArea", $(this).prop("href"));
        });
    };

    // once all is loaded
    $(window).load(function () {
        initVideos();
    });
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Ff7Mq/
Unfortunatly this library didn't work in jsfiddle. also up to jquery 1.7 support.
Perhaps someone knows an up-to-date plugin.

**EDIT:** only CSS was required to make it work ^^

Comment: Its working... video is embeded... but how to show the content of respective tab in the middle dialogue box as shown in above screenshot..

Comment: Are you talking about an extra layer shown with the source information of the video? Or where do you need to fetch your video url's from?

Comment: no there is one orange border box inbetween link and video... there i want to display some information about video... there will be 5 different information of 5 videos... those also should be displayed on respective tab hover...

Comment: You would fetch the extra content with a jquery selector and pass it to another jquery selector `.html()` or `.text()`.

Comment: I've updated the second fiddle, take a look to see if this is something you require.

Comment: Principle remains the same!

Answer (score 1):

```
I have made one simple fiddle as per your requirement. Please check below link.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvbsr/2/

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer, more like a comment.